# Form elements with a name attribute that is the same as a form-property, shadow/override the native form-property. Is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

If you have an `input` element in a form with the same name as a form's native property, then that element will shadow the native property.

For example, consider the following form:

```
<form id = "test">
    <input name="tagName" type="text" />
    <input name="nodeName" type="text" />
</form>
```

The `form` element's `tagName` and `nodeName` both normally return `FORM`. But in this case, the following code:

```
var f = document.getElementById("test");

console.log(f.tagName);
console.log(f.nodeName);
console.log(f["tagName"]);
console.log(f["nodeName"]);
```

displays:

```
<input name=​"tagName" type=​"text">​ 
<input name=​"nodeName" type=​"text">​
<input name=​"tagName" type=​"text">​
<input name=​"nodeName" type=​"text">​
```

Is there a workaround for this (other than renaming the fields)? `getAttribute` works for things like `name`, `action`, or `method`, but not for properties like `nodeName` or `tagName`.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8x3W/).

**Something even more interesting**: in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8x3W/2/) I'm simply logging the form itself. Normally that would show you the HTML, but now Chrome simply logs `TypeError`.

Comment: Hmm... `f.getAttribute('nodeName')` works fine? Or is it not cross-browser supported (I tested on Chrome)?

Comment: I can't think of a way.

Comment: @Colandus Really? In chrome it returns `null` for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R8x3W/1/ Yes it shows `10` on Chrome.

Comment: @Colandus Oh that's not what I was going for. I'd like it to return `FORM`, as it should. I am not talking about attributes, I am talking about the properties on the form object.

Comment: @TimDown That's too bad. It seems like a very strange limitation.

Comment: I could be wrong. Doing some research now.

Comment: @TimDown Same here; I've been looking around for a while but haven't come across anything.

Comment: I suppose you could clone the node without its children and query that: `f.cloneNode(false).nodeName`

Comment: I suggest adding some sort of suffix or prefix to the input names eg `<input name="el_tagName" type="text" />`

Comment: @JohnRooney This code is beyond my control. The users of my library may write code like this and so I cannot make any assumptions.

Comment: @TimDown That's a pretty good workaround Tim; it works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing it directly on the `<form>` element. The best I can think of is creating a clone of the element without any descendants and examining the clone's properties:

```
var clonedForm = f.cloneNode(false);
console.log(clonedForm.nodeName);
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments, this has the same problem in that `cloneNode` can be overridden in the same way as `nodeName`. Since any property of the form can be overridden, this makes it a difficult problem to overcome.

Comment: That works perfectly, Tim! So odd that there is a limitation like this. There should be a way to access the native properties even if you have form elements with the same name as a native property.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: It goes back to pre-DOM days of Netscape 2 and 3, when form elements were pretty much the only things that were scriptable. Browser developers were much more cavalier about deciding how JavaScript could access things back then, hence oddities like this and elements being accessible as properties of the global variable via their ID (you can thank Microsoft for that one, I think).

Comment: yes I remember (having worked on web pages in the dark days of IE6). I didn't realize that it would end up shadowing native properties and I thought there would be some other way to access it. I was just reminded of the "global variable via their ID" today by someone else... I had forgotten about that.

Comment: cloneNode can be overridden in the exact same way as nodeName. This solution won't work in the general case.

Comment: Note: you can detect this condition but there is no work around besides writing a custom parser. See _isClobbered at https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/master/src/purify.js

Comment: @Alok: Yes. Even the `elements` property can be overridden, which I had hoped wasn't the case, so my update is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I understand better what you want. Every `form` element has a property called `elements`:

```
var f = document.getElementById("test");
f.elements.tagName
f.elements.nodeName
```

Edit 2: If you want `f.tagName` to return `"FORM"` in this case, you can't. You've overwritten the native property. If you really need to use "tagName" as a name, then maybe you could use bracket or dot notation:

```
HTML: <input type="text" name="element.tagName">
JS: f.elements["element.tagName"]

HTML: <input type="text" name="element[tagName]">
JS: f.elements["element[tagName]"]
```

Edit 3: Some browsers have a DOM property called `localName` which could work, as long as you don't have a form field inside whose name is "localName".

Basically, don't use native DOM property names as the values of form field name attributes.

Comment: He wants it's children attribute! not form itself

Comment: That will only work for attributes like `method` and `action`. It doesn't work for native properties like `tagName`; it returns `null` in that case.

Comment: I think you have it backwards. :) When I access `f.tagName`, I want to get back `FORM`, and not the input element. Doing `f.elements.tagName` returns the same thing (the `input` element).

Comment: Thanks Greg. The problem is that I don't have control over the form. This has to do with code for a library that I've written. In some cases I check the tagname of the element to see what its type is and in cases like this, I am unable to do that. So I was wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround. You have to change the name attribute.

Comment: @GregBurghardt So in general how would you check to see if an element is a `form` element, without using `tagName` or `nodeName`, or indeed, *any* property of the `form` element (since they can all be overridden)?

Comment: In general, I would assume that native properties do not refer to form field objects, and work on fixing the name attributes of the offending form fields.

Comment: @GregBurghardt As would I. The problem is I cannot make any assumptions about the code that *others* may write. I can perhaps do some sort of filtering, or provide a warning/error if they have any form elements that share the same name as a native form property. But it really seems like a serious limitation.

Comment: You are correct, you cannot guard yourself against the code others write, but you cannot account for the stupidity of others either. Those other developers need to fix their code. This is not your problem. It is theirs. Prepare to pass the Buck!! :)